# xcolor, Y U NO decent cyan?

Tags: color

And Magenta too - I tried to \definecolor my own pure cyan and magenta in the obvious way and both are noticeably off (yellow too, if you look close). Is this a feature in the sense it will look more correct on a color printer this way (I couldn't try yet, I haven't one...) and I should *not* overwrite xcolor's defaults?  Even stranger is that I can't spot a difference when it comes to red, green, blue. (Note that other "special" colors also aren't necessarily that what you might expect.)

MWE (Minimum Working Eyesore, w/o packages)

```
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{test1}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{test2}{rgb}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{test3}{rgb}{0,255,0}
\definecolor{test4}{rgb}{0,255,255}
\definecolor{test5}{rgb}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{test6}{rgb}{255,0,255}
\definecolor{test7}{rgb}{255,255,0}
\definecolor{test8}{rgb}{255,255,255}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\noindent
\textcolor{test2}{$\bullet$} \textcolor{blue}{$\bullet$}\\
\textcolor{test3}{$\bullet$} \textcolor{green}{$\bullet$}\\
\textcolor{test5}{$\bullet$} \textcolor{red}{$\bullet$}\\
\textcolor{test4}{$\bullet$} \textcolor{cyan}{$\bullet$}\\
\textcolor{test6}{$\bullet$} \textcolor{magenta}{$\bullet$}\\
\textcolor{test7}{$\bullet$} \textcolor{yellow}{$\bullet$}\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: The conversion of RGB to CMYK is complicated (see the `xcolor` manual): is there a reason you are not simply using 'real' process colours here?

Comment: `xcolor` does `\definecolor{cyan}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}` which turns out to be different from `{rgb}{0,1,1}` because of different color models. By the way, if you want to specify RGB colors in integer notation, you need `\definecolor{test4}{RGB}{0,255,255}`. In this case it is the same, but you'd be surprised that `\definecolor{mytest}{rgb}{0,3,4}` also displays the same color as `test4`.

Comment: You might find the HTML/CSS/SVG color names more familiar? With the `[svgcolors]` option, you can use `Cyan` and all the other standard names.

Comment: `rgb` takes values in the range 0 to 1 so 255 will just get some value from overflowing the conversion

Comment: @egreg: Sorry for the 255, didn't pay attention :-) So the color models are not equivalent? (Shouldn't have surprised me, printer ink probably can't be exactly tuned to RGB.) Well, I wait for a printout.